# php foreach with multiple

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

my html is like this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="input_1[]</td>
<td><input tpye="text" name="input_2[]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="input_1[]</td>
<td><input tpye="text" name="input_2[]</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

on submit, the values get posted to the next site.

i know how to handle one `array[]`, like this:

```
foreach($array as $var) {
echo $var;
}
```

so, my problem is, i have to build an sql-Query inside the for each, it should be like

```
$sql="INSERT into table (value1,value2) VALUES (input_1,input_2)"
```

how can this be solved, i dont think for each can handle something like this:

```
foreach($array1 as $var1, $array2 as $var2){ 
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `for` loop to make it happen:

```
<?php

$a = $_POST['input_1'];
$b = $_POST['input_2'];

for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++) {

    $sql="INSERT into table (value1,value2) VALUES ('{$a[$i]}','{$b[$i]}')";
    echo $sql .'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$key` in the foreach, but this requires that the key exists in both arrays. You can easily check that with `isset()`.

```
$arr1 = array(...);
$arr2 = array(...);

foreach($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    echo $arr1[$key];
    echo $arr2[$key];
}
```

Comment: what value is key exactly? i don't understand :/

Comment: You can change $key to $cats if you like! No, but it takes all the keys in the array, one by one. Test print $key out and you will see :)

Answer (score 1):

In your `HTML` tpye should be `type`. Try like below

**In HTML**

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="input_1[]"> </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input_2[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="input_1[]"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="input_2[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**In PHP (test.php)**

```
$post = $_POST; 
$count = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($post['input_1']); $i++){
    $inp1 = $post['input_1'][$count];
    $inp2 = $post['input_2'][$count];
    $sql = "INSERT into table (value1,value2) VALUES ('$inp1', '$inp2')";
    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, take a look at your html:

```
<td><input type="text" name="input_1[]</td>
```

should be

```
<td><input type="text" name="input_1[]"/></td>
```

First solution, if you use **PDO** to connect to your database:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { //if something posted to server
    $array = array($_POST['input_1'], $_POST['input_2']);
    $stmt  = $db->prepare("INSERT into table (value1, value2) VALUES (?, ?)");
    foreach($array as $key) {
        $stmt->execute(array($key[0], $key[1]));
    }
}
```

Here the second solution if you use **MySQLi**:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
     $array = array($_POST['input_1'], $_POST['input_2']);
     $stmt  = $db->prepare("INSERT into table (value1, value2) VALUES (?, ?)");
     foreach($array as $key) {
         $stmt->bind_param('ss', $key[0], $key[1]);
         $stmt->execute();
     }
     $stmt->close();
 }
```

I am using prepared statements here because 1. it is faster and 2. it reduces the risk of [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) by a lot. Keep in mind that we take user input here and this is never safe!